# Is there any way to run No-GUI Ubuntu Server in VM(Windows host), and run GUI Linux apps rendered in Windows?

Tags: linux, windows, virtual-machine, virtualization

Title.

Is it possible to render the GUI on the host: Windows, when the backend part is provided by Ubuntu Server running in VM? So that we have both Full fledged Windows and Linux at the same time.

Comment: The only thing I have seen is Unity Mode in VMware Workstation Pro, but I think Unity mode is only for Windows.  (verified here that Unity is only for Windows and not Linux) .So unlikely you can get what you want.

Comment: I suppose you can make it use some X server running on Windows (Xming whatsoever) via TCP, but you'll still need to run the program from a shell of the VM. Honestly I'm not seeing the sense of your idea, and its performance wouldn't be great. The closest thing that makes some sense these days is WSL(g).

Comment: @TomYan I have tried running Ubuntu Desktop in VM, the performance is very bad, but server runs fine. I am trying to solve this problem. And we can SSH into the server them Windows.